# Starting Intel XDK with Broadband Connection

Tags: windows-10, intel, intel-xdk, dial-up

I'm unable to start Intel XDK. I'm using a broadband connection on windows 10. The error shows that I need to use an automatic configuration script or use a proxy server. But I am unable to do that and can't run XDK. Do I need to use a router or is there a way to fix the problem?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is a direct set up of a ppoe broadband connection on the pc. I needed to reinstall windows and now using a router. The problem is solved. There might be some other ways to delete registry or something. The bottom line is broadband connection set up creates problem for Intel XDK start up.